# Convert Custom Object records

Tags: trigger, custom-object, appexchange

I'm trying to use/modify the code in this free app to be able to convert/move a Custom Object associated with a Lead to the converted Account & Contact.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003GuisEAC

Its not working for me and I can't figure out why. I reached out to the developer awhile ago and still haven't heard back.

I've installed in my sandbox and updated the code to reference my custom object "Qualification Criteria". I've created a sample record related to a lead, but when I convert a Lead record - the related "Qualification Criteria" record does not get converted over to the Account/Contact. (It just remains associated with the Lead, which has since been converted of course)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

TRIGGER

```
trigger UpdateCustomeObject_Trigger on Lead (before update) { //This trigger will associate a Custom Object record with the contact and opportunity associated to the  //lead after it has been converted. //The Custom Object is associated to an opportunity only if an opportunity record exist on the Lead.
    for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++){
        if (Trigger.new[i].IsConverted == true && Trigger.old[i].isConverted == false){
            Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>();
            for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) 
                leadIds.add(lead.Id);

            Map<Id, Qualification_Criteria__c> entries = new Map<Id, Qualification_Criteria__c>([select Contact__c, Opportunity__c, Account__c, Lead__c from Qualification_Criteria__c where lead__c in :leadIds]);        
            if(!Trigger.new.isEmpty()) {
                for (Lead lead : Trigger.new)  {
                    for (Qualification_Criteria__c Qualification_Criteria : entries.values()) {
                        if (Qualification_Criteria.Lead__c == lead.Id) {
                            Qualification_Criteria.contact__c = lead.ConvertedContactId;
                            Qualification_Criteria.opportunity__c = lead.ConvertedOpportunityId;
                            Qualification_Criteria.account__c = lead.ConvertedAccountId;
                            update Qualification_Criteria;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

TEST CLASS

```
@isTest
//This is a test case for a situation where a lead will be converted.  The developer must explicitly call the convert lead
//method to simulate the user action.

private class TestTriggerCustomObjectUpdate {
        static testMethod void TestReferralUpdate() {
        // Insert the Lead
        List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
        Lead leadt = new Lead (FirstName ='fname', LastName ='test', Company ='myCompany');
        insert leadt;
        // Insert the custom object Record 
        Qualification_Criteria__c Qualification_Criteria = new Qualification_Criteria__c (Lead__c = leadt.Id);
        insert Qualification_Criteria;        

        //Convert the Lead
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(leadt.Id);
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);    

        //Requery for the referral record to see if it is updated
        Qualification_Criteria__c ref_upd = [select Account__c, Contact__c, Opportunity__c from Qualification_Criteria__c where Lead__c = :leadt.Id];

        //Check that the test passed
        System.assertEquals(ref_upd.Account__c,[Select ConvertedAccountId From Lead Where Id = :Qualification_Criteria.Lead__c].ConvertedAccountId);
        System.assertEquals(ref_upd.Contact__c,[Select ConvertedContactId From Lead Where Id = :Qualification_Criteria.Lead__c].ConvertedContactId);
        System.assertEquals(ref_upd.Opportunity__c,[Select ConvertedOpportunityId From Lead Where Id = :Qualification_Criteria.Lead__c].ConvertedOpportunityId);       

        //Test if no opty is created
        string NoOpty = 'Y';        
        if (NoOpty =='Y'){
            Lead leadto = new Lead (FirstName ='fnameo', LastName ='testo', Company ='myCompanyo');
            insert leadto;
            // Insert the custom object record 
            Qualification_Criteria__c Qualification_Criteriao = new Qualification_Criteria__c (Lead__c = leadto.Id);
            insert Qualification_Criteriao;

            Database.LeadConvert lco = new database.LeadConvert();
            lco.setLeadId(leadto.Id);
            lco.isDoNotCreateOpportunity();
            lco.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
            LeadStatus convertStatuso = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
            lco.setConvertedStatus(convertStatuso.MasterLabel);
            Database.LeadConvertResult lcro = Database.convertLead(lco); 

            Qualification_Criteria__c ref_updo = [select Account__c, Contact__c, Opportunity__c from Qualification_Criteria__c where Lead__c = :leadto.Id];

            //Check that the test passed
            System.assertEquals(ref_updo.Account__c,[Select ConvertedAccountId From Lead Where Id = :Qualification_Criteriao.Lead__c].ConvertedAccountId);
            System.assertEquals(ref_updo.Contact__c,[Select ConvertedContactId From Lead Where Id = :Qualification_Criteriao.Lead__c].ConvertedContactId);
            System.assert(ref_updo.Opportunity__c == null);
        }   
    }

    static testMethod void testBulkUpdate() {
        List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();       
        for (Integer i=0;i<5;i++) {
            Lead l = new Lead (FirstName ='bulk', LastName ='Test', Company ='myCompanyo');
            insert l;
            // Insert the custom Record 
            Qualification_Criteria__c r = new Qualification_Criteria__c (Lead__c = l.Id);
            insert r;

            //Convert the Lead
            Database.LeadConvert lcb = new database.LeadConvert();
            lcb.setLeadId(l.Id);
            LeadStatus convertStatusb = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
            lcb.setConvertedStatus(convertStatusb.MasterLabel);
            Database.LeadConvertResult lcrb = Database.convertLead(lcb);

            Qualification_Criteria__c bulkup = [select Account__c, Contact__c, Opportunity__c from Qualification_Criteria__c where Lead__c =:l.Id];

            //Check that the test has passed
            System.assertEquals(bulkup.Account__c,[Select ConvertedAccountId From Lead Where Id = :r.Lead__c].ConvertedAccountId);
            System.assertEquals(bulkup.Contact__c,[Select ConvertedContactId From Lead Where Id = :r.Lead__c].ConvertedContactId);
            System.assertEquals(bulkup.Opportunity__c,[Select ConvertedOpportunityId From Lead Where Id = :r.Lead__c].ConvertedOpportunityId);
            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: Well even if it works, I wont use it since a basic governor limit has been violated.NO SOQL inside for loop

Answer (score 3):

I think your logic is not Salesforce oriented. Avoid to put SQL query into your loop, that's really not best practice. There is a lot of useless steps in your code. Try more something like that :

```
trigger UpdateCustomeObject_Trigger on Lead (before update) 
{
    List<Qualification_Criteria__c> entries = new List<Qualification_Criteria__c>();

    for (Qualification_Criteria__c Qualification_Criteria : [   select  Contact__c, Opportunity__c, Account__c, Lead__c
                                                                from    Qualification_Criteria__c 
                                                                where   Lead__c in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]) 
    {
        Lead lead = Trigger.newMap.get(Qualification_Criteria.Lead__c);
        if (lead != null && lead.isConverted == true && Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id).isConverted == false) 
        {
            Qualification_Criteria.contact__c = lead.ConvertedContactId;
            Qualification_Criteria.opportunity__c = lead.ConvertedOpportunityId;
            Qualification_Criteria.account__c = lead.ConvertedAccountId;
            entries.add(Qualification_Criteria);
        }
    }
    update entries;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response! Unfortunately that still didn't work. I tried changing the trigger to "(after update)" it did work. (yay!) Any concerns with using this method?